# IOS 8.0.2 Calendar on iPhone 5 not syncing with MS Exchange properly

Tags: ios, calendar, exchange

Since I upgraded my iPhone 5 to iOS 8.0.2 I have started having issues with the calendar syncing through Microsoft Exchange. The event description created on the iPhone do not appear on Outlook, only the subject and address are synchronised. The description of the event remains blank on Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

Try Settings; Mail, Contacts, Calendars; Default Calendar. 
Make certain that your Exchange server calendar is the default calendar.